# How to import messy .txt and drop timestamp using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, read.csv

I am trying to import a txt file with huge amounts of transaction data. Normally I could open the file in Excel and then save as CSV but the file is too large so I have been using Python 3:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_name", sep = "\s+", dtype = str)
```

This gives a somewhat usable data frame but now I have some problems with the date and time stamp.

In the txt file these are saved as:

```
2016-12-11 00:00:00.000 "XXXX"  "XXXX"  "XXXXX" "X"
```

The X's are other data. When I import this data into Python I get the date as an index, with the time stamp in the date column followed by the other variables:

```
                VAR1.           VAR2.   VAR3.   VAR4.   VAR5. 
2016-12-11      00:00:00.000    XXXX    XXXX    XXXXX   X
```

I tried using the following to create a new index when I import the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_name", sep = "\s+", dtype = str, index_col = False)
```

But this ended up pushing VAR5 off of the data frame and assigning the timestamp to VAR2.

```
       VAR1.           VAR2.       VAR3.     VAR4.   VAR5. 
1   2016-12-11      00:00:00.000    XXXX    XXXX    XXXXX
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with importing the data from a txt file into python, dropping the time stamp, and then applying datetime to the first column.

The txt file has  some large white spaces between variables and each string is encapsulated with "" eg:

```
2016-12-11 00:00:00.000 "XXXX"  "XXX"   "XXXX"  "X"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sep = "\t"`? Its more likely the text is tab delimited

Comment: You may be able to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121008/pandas-read-csv-ignore-separator-in-last-column) but adapt it for first column instead of last

Comment: Try read_table? It handles white spaces better

Comment: You can also try `read_fwf` function.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh I used `sep = "\t"` and got it!